# Cordova screen orientation plugin not working

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, screen-orientation, intel-xdk

I'm using Intel XDK and Cordova to create a simple app. I am currently trying to lock the screen orientation in 'portrait' mode.

I tried:

- Setting the orientation in 'Build settings' in Intel XDK
- Setting the orientation in the config file (intelxdk.config.additions.xml) as such: `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />`
- The Cordova Core Plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

So far nothing has worked. I think the plugin should work, but I am afraid I am implementing it in the wrong way. I started with this (it's the already existing app.js file which is linked in the HTML head section, I just added 1 line of code):

```
document.addEventListener("app.Ready", onAppReady, false) ;

function onAppReady() {
if( navigator.splashscreen && navigator.splashscreen.hide ) { 
        navigator.splashscreen.hide() ;
        screen.lockOrientation('portrait');        
    }
}

//window.screen.lockOrientation('portrait'); //Makes no difference
```

Should I place this code somewhere else? Other functions that I place in this location do work... 
Also, when I try to simulate the app, I get [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZqhf.jpg).
Even if I do something like `screen.lockOrientation('portrait', onAppReady, false);`

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

EDIT: So I just found out that a simple `console.log(screen.orientation)` or `console.log(window.screen.orientation)` already doesn't work. It logs "undefined". I added the plugin via the XDK Projects menu (other plugins added this way are working fine). Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this plugin work?

Comment: If you are working in xcode then you can directly stop or set screen orientation from xcode settings `General Setting`. IF.

Comment: It would be better though (if possible) to set at a higher level, in case the developer is or may target another platform too such as Android, rather than setting inside a specific platform.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the intel-xdk, but in Cordova, you can edit config.xml in the project root to include the `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` entry there, directly inside the `widget` element. If there is also a config.xml in your project, I'd recommend experimenting with putting this value there too.

Comment: Thanks! I really overthought it .... I was implementing plugins etc., not realizing all I needed was a simple entry in the config file.